# Не полностью переведена Справка по Markdown

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В разделах [Спойлеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers) и [Подсветка синтаксиса в коде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) часть текста на английском.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15081
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15089
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15078
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15086